# How to get code inside directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have the HTML:

```
<div my-directive>
  <--generic html-->
</div my-directive>
```

How could I go about getting `<--generic html-->` in the directive code of `my-directive` in Angular 1.4?

Comment: Use [ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I'll check that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transclude is a setting to tell angular to capture everything that is put inside the directive in the markup

more about this under Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements section on [documentation of directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

If you write a custom directive you use `ng-transclude` in the directive template to mark the point where you want to insert the contents of the element

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('hero', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { name:'@' },
      template: '<div>' +
                  '<div>{{name}}</div><br>' +
                  '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>'
    };
  });
```

If you put this in your markup

```
<hero name="superman">Stuff inside the custom directive</hero>
```

It would show up like:

> Superman
>
> Stuff inside the custom directive